# Apache virtual directory without redirect

Tags: apache, virtual-directory

What I'm trying to accomplish is pulling content from a directory that is not the same as the url path.  For example:

- URL: example.com/
- path: /www/production/

Currently, the root url pulls content from the path above.  What I want to do is something like this:

- URL: example.com/
- path: /www/production/root/

So the base URL "example.com" should pull data not from /www/production/ but from /www/production/root/.

I think this is called a Virtual Directory in IIS.  Is there something like this in Apache?

Edit for clarification:

I have a ton of existing content that I do not want to have to restructure yet.  However, the root site is being completely rebuilt and is going to be quite a bit bigger.  What I want is each microsite to have it's own directory, such that requests for example.com/ should pull content from /www/production/root/ while requests for example.com/microsite/ should still pull content from /www/production/microsite/.

Hopefully that makes more sense.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not exactly clear what your problem is. If you just want all URLs to be taken relative to some location on the server, then you can use the `DocumentRoot` directive:

```
DocumentRoot /www/production/root/
```

If you want to only have certain urls go to the new place, then you can either use the `Alias` or `AliasMatch` directives from the mod_alias module. These can map either prefixes on a URL, or url Regexes to other server locations. If even this isn't sufficient, you can use mod_rewrite which allows for arbitrary chains of url rewriting, but can get very hairy to maintain, so you're better off avoiding that module if you can.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Sorry if my post was a bit unclear.  Maybe my recent edit will help clarify the situation... although it sounds like mod_alias might be the way to go here... I'll have to peek at some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the following, in your VirtualHost config, does what you're asking for:

```
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /www/production/root/
```

Comment: Well, this won't actually work because there are other micro-sites that need to continue to be referenced by matching the url to the directory structure.  so example.com/sales/jobs/ pulls from /www/production/sales/jobs/.  What I'm trying to do is keep the rest of the server structure intact while not having to spill 60+ files into the root of the directory structure for the root site.  Make sense?